# How to use "print" or "show" from within a NetLogo Extension?

Tags: netlogo

I'm writing an extension that will perform a large search of an NK landscape when called. I'd like to have the extension "print" or "show" the search progress or specific values that may be found while the search is ongoing.  I used to know how to send a String to console from an extension, but cannot remember how to do so or find any documentation for getting control of the console from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in the GUI portion of the NetLogo code, so it's not part of the "official" extensions API.  But you can still use it.  The GIS extension does it like so (Java code):  https://github.com/NetLogo/GIS-Extension/blob/hexy/src/org/myworldgis/netlogo/GISExtensionState.java#L92-L112

Note the difference is usage between headless (BehaviorSpace) and GUI modes, if that matters for your extension.

```java
    public void displayWarning(String warning) {
        if (_workspace instanceof HeadlessWorkspace) {
            _workspace.warningMessage(warning);
        } else if (_workspace instanceof AbstractWorkspace) {
            AbstractWorkspace ws = (AbstractWorkspace) _workspace;
            ws.outputObject(warning, null, true, false, OutputDestinationJ.NORMAL());
        }
    }


    public void displayWarning(String warning, Object owner) {
        if (_workspace instanceof HeadlessWorkspace) {
            _workspace.warningMessage(warning);
        } else if (_workspace instanceof AbstractWorkspace) {
            AbstractWorkspace ws = (AbstractWorkspace) _workspace;
            try {
                ws.outputObject(warning, owner, true, false, OutputDestinationJ.NORMAL());
            } catch (LogoException e) {
                displayWarning(warning);
            }
        }
    }
```

And it captures the workspace instance from the extension manager, when it's passed into the extension state object here on the `runOnce` NetLogo calls on extension load:  https://github.com/NetLogo/GIS-Extension/blob/74b50dcf4ec26df55b7582d288d4f8b2171bbd09/src/org/myworldgis/netlogo/GISExtension.java#L101

Comment: Thanks!  Works exactly as needed!